Apply Multiple Rotations Around Different Pivot Points for a Single Element
I'm developing a game using basic JS that involves moving game pieces around a board. I'm running into an issue when trying to perform multiple transformations, specifically rotations.
The game requires that the pieces "pivot" around their top corners, then move in the direction they are facing after the rotation (see the example), and perform additional rotations as needed.
My issue is that, as soon as I add the transform-origin property to choose a pivot corner, the previous rotation gets messed up.

I'm searching for a way to retain the previous transformation, and then start clean with a new one on the next move.
CodePen

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rectangle Transformation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .inputs {
            margin: 20px;
        }

        .rectangle {
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: coral;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform-origin: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="inputs">
        <div>
            <span>Rotate:</span>
            <input type="range" id="rotate-slider" min="0" max="360" value="0" step="1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Move:</span>
            <input type="range" id="move-slider" min="0" max="360" value="0" step="1">
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Transform Origin: </span>
            <select onchange="selected(this)">
                <option>center</option>
                <option>top right</option>
                <option>top left</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rectangle" id="rectangle"></div>

    <script>
        const rectangle = document.getElementById('rectangle');
        const rotateSlider = document.getElementById('rotate-slider');
        const moveSlider = document.getElementById('move-slider');
        const select = document.querySelector('select');

        function updateRotation(angle) {
            rectangle.style.transform = `rotate(${angle}deg)`;
        }

        rotateSlider.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            let angle = e.target.value;
            if (select.value == 'top left') {
                angle = 360 - angle;
            }
            updateRotation(angle);
        });

        function selected(selectObject) {
            var value = selectObject.value;
            rectangle.style.transformOrigin = value;
        }

        function moveRectangle() {
            const distance = parseFloat(moveSlider.value);
            const angle = parseFloat(rotateSlider.value);

            const radians = angle * (Math.PI / 180);
            const moveY = distance * Math.cos(radians);
            const moveX = distance * Math.sin(radians);

            rectangle.style.left = `calc(50% + ${moveX}px)`;
            rectangle.style.top = `calc(50% + ${moveY * -1}px)`;
        }

        moveSlider.addEventListener('input', moveRectangle);
    </script>
</body>

</html>

Is my approach to this all wrong?

Using two nested elements, so that you can apply different transformations to the outer and the inner one, would probably be the easiest way to solve this.

Could you elaborate? The user should be able to make any number of transformations, the one included has three. So you'd need an additional nested element for every transformation, right?

I'd guess so, yes.
